# How to set values in one database by querying a different one in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Am a PL/SQL newbie... Am seeking a way to do this:

1. Query a database based on certain conditions.
2. Based on results of these conditions to update a different
   database's table with specific values.

e.g.

Database: A (contains data that I seek to query)

Database: B (contains table with 2 columns that I wish to update)

condition.sql:

```
select typ_cd
from A.mytable
where typ_cd = "AAA"

if typ_cd = "AAA" UPDATE B SET VAL = "P"
```

Would appreciate it if someone could how me how to convert my pseudocode into a working PL/SQL script.

Comment: First off, are you certain that you have two separate databases rather than two schemas in the same database?  What other products like SQL Server consider a "database" is more like a schema in Oracle so there is often some confusion over terminology.  Second, what is the relationship between the two tables?  Do you really want to update every row in B to have a VAL of 'P'?  Or do you want to update a particular row or set of rows in B (i.e. only those rows where typ_cd = 'AAA')?  Third, is your condition on A really just to check whether a typ_cd 'AAA' row exists?

Comment: Yes, its two different schemas in the same Oracle 11g database. Basically, I am writing tests using PL/SQL scripts with A being the database with actual data and B being the database containing the following attributes (column names): name of the test SQL script, status ("P" for Pass, "F" for Fail), a column for timestamp, and another one for unique ID. Should there be a relationship?

Comment: Two different schemas definitely makes things easier since we don't have to create a database link.  There needs to be some way of determining which row in the table in the B schema needs to be updated based on the result of your query against A.  Perhaps you know what particular row you want to update in the table in B based on other local variables in your PL/SQL code rather than based on the data in A?  Otherwise, there would need to be some relationship between the tables or some other way of determining which row in the table in B needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE 
   cursor item_cursor 
   is 
      select typ_cd 
        from A.mytable 
       where typ_cd = "AAA";

   item_val item_cursor%ROWTYPE ;
   cnt INTEGER(5) := 0 ;
BEGIN 
   open item_cursor ;
   loop
      fetch item_cursor into item_val ;
      exit when item_cursor%NOTFOUND ;
      cnt := cnt + 1 ;
   end loop ;
   close item_cursor ;

   if (cnt > 0)
   then 
      insert into B 
      values(cnt) ;
   end if ;
END;
/
```

I hope this should work.

Happy querying....

Shanmugam